# what is the differance between input and Id selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('input[Id="RadioId"]');
```

and

```
$('#RadioId');
```

Iam using `RadioId` as common id for two radio buttons,when i use first one i get two jQuery objects,next one gives me only one object.
Why the second selector gives me only one object when there are two with the same Id?

Comment: Ids need to unique you cant use like that way

Comment: Ids should be unique. Use class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one, `$('input[Id="RadioId"]');` does not apply the rules for searching for an Id as it could be any attribute you supply in this markup. E.g. you could search for class instead (`$('input[class="RadioId"]');`). So it will return all elements it finds.

The second one `$('#RadioId');` searches only for the Id. As an Id should be unique, it will only return one object and it believes there should only be one. Therefore you only get the single object.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique So, Your Question and Code becomes Wrong ,but if u r thinking about classes,

Difference:

```
$('input[class="RadioClass"]');
```

You can have `input type="text"` with class RadioClass to target ONLY INPUTS Not divs ,or span,

```
$('.RadioClass');
```

But here $('.RadioClass'); u can target Any HTML element say Simple div or span.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the violation of the html coding, your ids are duplicated! **ids must be unique**

when you select like `$('input[id="RadioId"]');` it returns all the matched elements, while `$('#RadioId');` returns only the first matched element, because as I mentioned above ids must be unique, so jQuery assumes that there should be only one of this id.